# How to map .json to .html url in spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am working on a Spring 4.2 MVC application. Here I am trying to invoke a .html extention url that is supposed to return json data. The problem is that I am getting a org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException when controller invokes the specific url. This works perfectly if i give the .json extention instead of .html.

I am using the following jars for json mapping

`jackson-annotations-2.8.7.jar
jackson-core-2.8.7.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar
jackson-datatype-joda-2.8.7.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.7.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.7.jar
json-simple-1.1.jar`

Following is my java based config instead of web.xml

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
return new String[] { "*.html", "*.json"};
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
}

private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement( LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
return multipartConfigElement;
}

private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                            // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.

private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0; // Size threshold after which files will be written to disk

}
```

My controller method is as below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getDetails.html", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String getDetails(@RequestBody String id, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    logger.info("getDetails");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // do something
}       
}
```

I have an ajax call from where the url is invoked

```
                var getDetails = function() {
                    var id = {
                            "id" : $("#id").val()
                        }
                    $
                            .ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                url : "../data/getDetails.html",
                                data : JSON.stringify(id),
                                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                mimeType: "application/json",
                                dataType : 'json',
                                success : function(data) {
             // do something

               }
```

Following is from server log

`INFO  stdout:71 - 2017-10-16 12:13:53 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/App/data/getDetails.html]`

`DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/App/data/getDetails.html]
INFO  stdout:71 - 2017-10-16 12:13:53 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Looking up handler method for path /data/getDetails.html`

`DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Looking up handler method for path /data/getDetails.html`
`INFO  stdout:71 - 2017-10-16 12:13:53 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:131 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`

`DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:131 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`
`INFO  stdout:71 - 2017-10-16 12:13:53 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:250 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalExceptionController'`

`DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:250 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalExceptionController'`

Please help!

Comment: try to use `produces = "text/plain"`

Comment: @SachinGupta tried that not working

Comment: @SachinGupta I hav updated the question with server log

Comment: Remove `produces` tag, then run

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sachin you saved my day. Please post it as an answr so that I can accept.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `produces` tag from `@RequestMapping` annotation. then It will work.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have access to comment on your post..so comment on my post..)

did you try `consumes= "application/json"` like `produces = "application/json"` in your annotations?

And

In your ajax call, you used both contentType and dataType. You are expecting response in json format right?

Comment: as per your exception.did you try produces = {  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} ?

Comment: temporarily you may comment mimeType in the ajax call.It should work with out this.

Comment: to return the java object in json formate from controller you may use Gson api.use toJson()/fromJson() to convert jsonString/java

Comment: returning json format is already working when using .json... Here the problem is controller is not even able to map the call properly

Comment: the problem here seems to be .html format not being acceptable for json

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using default
spring mvc config. It uses **InternalResourceViewResolver** by default. What you need to do is configure **ContentNegotiatingViewResolver** which tries to resolve views based on content type. I am not posting an example because you will find many on internet.

I would recommend that you read about REST endpoints and use proper notations and standards while writing your endpoints. For example, in your question you have an endpoint with .html which returns json response is quite correct.